# Type is undefined MVC AJAX Script

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In one page of my application I get *Type is undefined* error on the AJAX script.

Why would this be?

Error message:

> Type is not defined
>   MicrosoftMvcAjax.js()()Microsof...vcAjax.js
>   (line 6)
>   [Break on this error]
>   Type.registerNamespace('Sys.Mvc');
>   Sys.Mv...reate_AjaxOptions=function(){return {};}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start off by installing Firebug for Firefox - it will give you a better error message complete with a call stack.

Sounds like you are trying to instantiate something that is not defined, perhaps you didn't include a javascript file?

Comment: i guess order of the scripts on the page matters?

Comment: Yes it does. If something is defined in foo.js and bar.js loads before foo.js and calls something in foo.js it will fail.

Answer (score 9):

You have to add a reference to MicrosoftAjax.js as well

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this - 'Type' is undefined. **Igor Zeveka** gave a nice hint and it worked for me. 
'Type' class is defined in MS AJAX library. I was referencing my custom.js file in my html head section. Looks like that was causing this reference issue. 
I moved my custom.js reference inside  section of ScriptManager.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
   <Scripts>       
       <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/MyJscripts/custom.js"  />
   </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```